# Total purchase count by product for current user in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce, I would like to show the total purchase product count for the current user in single product pages. Like for example if John bought a Pen 2 times then it displays the count *("2")* in this product page for John user and if Jack bought it 5 times then it will show 5 in this product page for Jack user.

I don't want print total sold count, I want to show as per current logged in user.

My actual code in function.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wc_product_sold_count() {
    $get_current_pro_id = $_SESSION["iddd"];

    global $product;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID,  $product->get_id() )  )
    {

        $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
//echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';

        return $units_sold;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done easily with a very light SQL query in your hooked function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wc_product_sold_count() {
    // Only for logged in users
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return; // Exit for non logged users

    global $wpdb, $product;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Current User ID
    $product_id = $product->get_id(); // Current Product ID

    // The SQL request
    $units_bought = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(woim2.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim2 ON woi.order_item_id = woim2.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
        WHERE woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
        AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'
        AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'
        AND woim2.meta_key = '_qty'
    ");
    
    // Display count if is greater than zero
    if( $units_bought > 0 ){
        $label = __( 'Units bought' , 'woocommerce' ); // Label
        
        // Output
        echo '<p class="units-bought"><strong>' . $label . ': </strong>' . $units_bought . '</p>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).* Tested and works.

Related: [Display the total purchase count of a specific product for customer in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999725/display-the-total-purchase-count-of-a-specific-product-for-customer-in-woocommer/53002761#53002761)

[image]