# Change dynamically product price based on user related purchases in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

When I added this `$product->get_id()` I got `HTTP Error 500`
and got this message in error log:

> [13-Mar-2018 08:47:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   get_id() on null in
>   /home/healthnwellness/public_html/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/functions.php
>   on line 926

My function is in `functions.php`:

```
//Function return price (commission based)  as per their purchase count 
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $product;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $count_purchase = wc_product_sold_count();

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() )  )
    {

        if($count_purchase == 1){
            $price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_comm_1_kit');
            $post_id =  $product->get_id();

            $price = ($price[0]);
            return $price;
        }
        elseif($count_purchase == 2){
            $price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_comm_2_kit');
            $post_id =  $product->get_id();

            $price = ($price[0]);
            return $price;
        }           
        elseif($count_purchase >= 3){
            $price = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_comm_3_kit');
            $post_id = $product->get_id();

            $price = ($price[0]);
            return $price;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $price = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_discounted_price');
        $post_id = $product->get_id();

        $price = ($price[0]);
        return $price;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error? what I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Note: The `wc_product_sold_count()` function comes [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49184812) and  has been changed to return the count only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some missing parts and a lot of errors in your code.

You need laso to make changes the function a bit `wc_product_sold_count()` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49184812).

So try this instead:

```
function wc_product_sold_count_for_user( $product, $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $product_id = $product->get_id(); // Current Product ID

    // The SQL request
    return $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(woim2.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim2 ON woi.order_item_id = woim2.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
        WHERE woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'
        AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'
        AND woim2.meta_key = '_qty'
    ");
}

//Function return price (commission based)  as per their purchase count
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price','return_custom_price', 10, 2);
function return_custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    // If user is not logged in return the default price
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $price;

    $customer = wp_get_current_user();
    $count_purchase = wc_product_sold_count_for_user( $product, $customer->ID );

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer->user_email, $customer->ID, $product->get_id() ) ){

        if( $count_purchase == 1 )
            $price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_comm_1_kit', true );
        elseif( $count_purchase == 2 )
            $price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_comm_2_kit', true );
        elseif( $count_purchase >= 3 )
            $price = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_comm_3_kit', true );
    } else {
        $price = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_discounted_price', true );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product->get_id() = $_SESSION["iddd"];
```

Is a faulty assignment. The `get_id()` returns an int, and you try to set it with another value.

It also appears before the `global $product;` now so it will be null.

Comment: i removed this like now please review and solve thanks

Comment: can you post your return_custom_price hook? because the $product is not passed into this function, or is null

Comment: 'add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);' here is the hook

Comment: @Mukhyyar what happens if you remove `global $product?` I dont think that belongs there, as the procuct is being passed as an argument