# Display the total purchase count of a specific product for customer in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, product

In Woocommerce, I would like to show total count of a specific product on a different page than the product for the current customer.

So I have tryied to change the answer code from this thread: 
[Total purchase count by product for current user in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184187/total-purchase-count-by-product-for-current-user-in-woocommerce/52999655#52999655)

But I don't know how to set the product ID as the function is using the global variable product.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You just nee to make a very little change in the function like:

```
function wc_product_sold_count( $product_id ) {
    // Only for logged in users
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return; // Exit for non logged users

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Current User ID

    // The SQL request
    $units_bought = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(woim2.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim2 ON woi.order_item_id = woim2.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
        WHERE woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'
        AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'
        AND woim2.meta_key = '_qty'
    ");

    // Display count if is greater than zero
    if( $units_bought > 0 ){
        $label = __( 'Units bought' , 'woocommerce' ); // Label

        // Returned output
        return '<p class="units-bought"><strong>' . $label . ': </strong>' . $units_bought . '</p>';
    }
}

// The shortcode from this function
add_shortcode('product_sold_count', 'shortcode_product_sold_count');
function shortcode_product_sold_count( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_sold_count' );

    return wc_product_sold_count( $atts['id'] );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

USAGE Examples:

1) As a shortcode in a page in the Wordpress Text Editor *(replace `37` by your product ID)*:

```
[product_sold_count id="37"]
```

2) In any php code *(replace `37` by your product ID)*:

```
echo wc_product_sold_count( 37 );
```

Comment: are you sure that query works fine? example: woim2 not found anywhere as alias in query