# Display WooCommerce monthly sales count for products created by a user in his profile

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, product

I would like to display the sales count of the products created by a user. Ideally, I'd like to sort this data by months within their user profile.

I tried using [Total purchase count by product for current user in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184187/total-purchase-count-by-product-for-current-user-in-woocommerce/49184812#49184812) answer code to customize it, but have no idea how I get this in the profile of the user who created the product.

Is there a workaround?